# Android TabLayout doesn't change Tab (Fragment) when clicked

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Regarding TabLayout, when I swipe left or right, the next tab is inflated - fragment is shown properly - however, when I click the tab title, it doesn't not automatically change to the proper fragment. Does this have to be implemented manually? Seems a bit weird as swiping works by default, so clicking should as well.

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this ? i have the same problem right now.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement a `onTabSelectedListener` and use your `viewPager` to change the `fragment`.

Example:

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tabSelected)
    { 
      viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabSelected.getPosition()); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tabSelected){}

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tabSelected){

    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't help too..!! The onTabSelected callback is not getting called in that situation..So doesn't work as intented..1